# I want to send voice recording file(or file) from my android app to skype user. Not able to send file(target sdk version is 30)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider, skypedeveloper, voice-recording

I am recording user's voice and want to send recorded file(audio file) to skype. But not able to send   file on skype. Please suggest any working solution

Comment: grant read permission for your file with FileProvider and share it with skype or any app.

Comment: could you please post code segment that you use to send the recorded file? Also please check if you are asking for permission for file read/write access.

Comment: thanks for suggestions...both answers are useful